# BlackBerry 6 Regex

Tags: .net, blackberry, mobile

I have a regex for BlackBerry 6

Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry (?'deviceName'\w+); en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(.(?'minor'\d+)?)\w*) Mobile Safari/534.11+

But it doesn't seem to match this string:

Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry AAAA; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/X.X.X.X Mobile Safari/534.11+

What's wrong?  This is in the Browser Definition files for .NET 4.0

NOTE: For some reason the editor doesn't show my escaped characters either.  all of the / are escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input string actually contains a numeric version, like `6.5.4.3` instead of `X.X.X.X`, the following regex will match:

```
@"Mozilla\/5.0 \(BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry (?'deviceName'\w+); en-US\) AppleWebKit\/534\.11\+ \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Version\/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(.(?'minor'\d+)?)[\.\w]*) Mobile Safari\/534\.11\+"
```

In addition of having to escape all `/().+` characters, your regex didn't match the last two elements of the version number; since the `\w` character class does not mactch period characters.